# Compare two tables and find matches in ms-access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to compare two tables in ms access 2007 to find matches from the tables which I know to have one field in common. When I try to run the following query

```
SELECT
FROM FirstTrial INNER JOIN ConsolidatedDatabase 
ON FirstTrial.ModelNumbr = ConsolidatedDatabase.ModelNumbr;
```

I get an error 'Query must have at least one destination field'

What do I need to change in order to make the query work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need some fields:

```
SELECT *
FROM FirstTrial INNER JOIN ConsolidatedDatabase 
ON FirstTrial.ModelNumbr = ConsolidatedDatabase.ModelNumbr;
```

It would be better to put some names instead of *

In MS Access, you can use the query design window.

Comment: you mean the names of the fields from each table?

Comment: Yes, * implies that it will select every field in the table.  If you specify, it will only display the fields you want to see.